Question about a dua I’m making
Asalamualaykum warahmatulahi wabarakatu
I have a question about a dua I’m making, so I broke my nose in 2020 I got it fixed/ corrected they put the bones back in place but my nose didn’t go back to how it was before I broke it , it is now slightly crooked I am making dua right now that my nose goes back to how it looked before I broke it because i loved my nose and had no issues with it before but now I’m insecure about it and think about it a lot is it possible this can come true without going through surgery?
Even if I was to go through surgery they wouldn’t be able to restore it to its exact look and how Allah SWT created it .
The reason i believe this is very possible is because in 2021 I saw a tiktok video of a guy who said he broke his nose and didn’t get surgery on it but applied black seed oil to it and subhanallah it went back to normal, so what I’m doing now is applying black seed oil to my nose every night and begging Allah swt through dua that my nose goes back to the way it looked before I broke it it is a slight shift .
This is something that I want to come true so badly I’d do anything for it .. my question is is this possible??

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that I'm afraid your question is rather subjective and will attract opinion-based answers which means it is hardly on-topic and would make it a bad fit for the StackExchange model.
